# Transfer text from one stackpanel to the other

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm developing a UWP to do list.

I have two stack panels side by side.

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  />
        <RowDefinition  />
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="65"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <TextBlock Margin="10" FontSize="30">Please enter in an item you wish to complete</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox MinWidth="200" Name="Input"></TextBox>
            <Button Margin="10" Click="ButtonAdd_Click">Add</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Margin="10" FontSize="30">Below are the Items you need to complete</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="outputArea" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="completedList" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">

    </StackPanel>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Click="ButtonSettings_Click">Settings</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Click="ButtonClear_Click">Clear done</Button>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

The outputArea stackpanel contains the text which the user has entered in.
C# code

```
private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel(); ;
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        textbox.Text += Input.Text;
        textbox.IsReadOnly = true;
        CheckBox done = new CheckBox();
        done.Content = "check when done";
        done.Checked += Done_Checked;

        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        sp.Children.Add(textbox);
        sp.Children.Add(done);



        outputArea.Children.Add(sp);

    }
```

This code gets input from a text box and outputs it to the output area
My issue is that I'm trying to move the text from the output Area to the completed List when the checkbox is ticked. I have tried the following below

```
 private void Done_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // find the parent horiz sp, and move it.
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();

        textbox.Text += textbox.Text;
        textbox.IsReadOnly = true;
        StackPanel stackpanel = new StackPanel();

        stackpanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        stackpanel.Children.Add(textbox);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you aren't set completedList.Children.Add(stackpanel);   in done_checked event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
private void Done_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((CheckBox)sender);

    outputArea.Children.Remove(sp);
    completedList.Children.Add(sp);

}
```